# Many-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a schema *Definitions* which I would like to be able to reference itself. As I need meta data about the reference, there's a coupling schema named *Associations*. I'm using Entity Framework's fluent API in conjunction with data annotation attributes.

Definitions:

```
public class Definition
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }
}
```

Associations:

```
public class Association
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int AssociatedDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public int RootDefinitionId { get; set; }

    public virtual AssociationType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Definition AssociatedDefinition { get; set; }
    public virtual Definition RootDefinition { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Association>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.AssociatedDefinition)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal();

modelBuilder.Entity<Association>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.RootDefinition)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

I use MySQL as the database engine.
When I try to save a definition entity with an empty association collection, I get a constraint violation:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ("u0228621_8"."Definitions", CONSTRAINT
>   "FK_Definitions_Associations_Id" FOREIGN KEY ("Id") REFERENCES
>   "Associations" ("Id"))

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If Definition can exist without Association then replace HasRequired with HasOptional

Comment: Thank you @CodeNotFound. So _HasOptional_ means that _Association_ is optional from _Definition_'s perspective? If so, would I choose _WithOptionalPrincipal_ as an _Association_ wouldn't exist without a _Definition_?

Comment: I think you should used WithMany because Definition can have many Association. What is the purposes of Associations collection into Defintion class? If you have the exact purpose of that collection then I can tell you if you should use WithMany or not.

Comment: It's just meant to be an easy way for me to retrieve all associations for a specific definition. I hoped it would work with Entity Framework's lazy loading?

Comment: Then you need to add two collections `RootAssociations` and `Associations`. After that add `WithMany(p => p.Associations)` for the first fluent configurations. And add `WithMany(p => p.RootAssociations)` for the last fluent configurations. Remove WithRequiredPrincipal on all configurations.

Comment: But _RootDefinition_ should be the _Definition_ entity with the associations. A typical relationship would be A -> B & C where A is _RootDefinition_ and B and C are _AssociatedDefinition_. B & C aren't aware of A.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112203/discussion-between-leonard-and-codenotfound).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your association class with all relationships being "required:required" because of the `WithRequiredPrincipal` which doesn't seem to be what you want.  Since the `Associations` collection appears (from the comments) to be the relation *from* the Root definitions, the mapping should come from definition, like so:

```
// Foreign key mappings included.
modelBuilder.Entity<Definition>().HasMany(d => d.Assocations)
  .WithRequired(a => a.RootDefinition).HasForeignKey(a => a.RootDefinitionId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Association>().HasRequired(a => a.AssociatedDefinition)
  .HasForeignKey(a => a.AssociatedDefinitionId);
```

So the `Associations` collection may be empty, but every `Association` requires a `RootDefinition` and `AssociatedDefinition`.

Comment: Quick note from the question-comments: if there really is no mapping from assoc definition back to root, there may not be a use case for `Association.RootDefinition`, because you may always have the root `Definition` readily available (as the parent object of your `Association` collection).  Removing it (and the foreign key ID property) will simplify things for EF.  You could retain your current schema by changing the `.WithRequired(...)` above to `.WithRequired().Map(ca => ca.MapKey("RootDefinitionId"));`